# How can I make it return to view blade laravel after ajax process?

Tags: ajax, laravel, laravel-5.3, vuejs2, laravel-blade

My ajax (in vue component) like this :

```
<template>
    ...
    <a class="text-right" @click="detail">
        Detail
    </a>
    ...
</template>
<script>
    export default{
        ...
        methods:{
            ...
            detail() {
                this.$http.post(window.BaseUrl + '/shop/',{data: JSON.stringify(this.data)}).then(function (response) {
                    ...
                }).catch(function(error){
                    ...
                });
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

If user click a link, it will call detail method

In detail method used to send data via ajax

It will routes in laravel

The route like this :

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'shop','as'=>'shop.'], function () {
    Route::post('/', 'ShopController@index');
    ...
});
```

Then the route will call shop controller

The controller like this :

```
public function index(Request $request)
{
    $param = $request->only('data');
    $list = $this->shop_service->getList($param['cart_cache']);
    return view('shop.index',compact('list'));
}
```

If the code executed, I want it will redirect to view blade laravel (`return view('shop.index',compact('list'));`)

How can I do it?

Comment: Inside your `ajax request` if the request succeeded `window.location = "/whatever";`

Comment: See this question might help you, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/199099/how-to-manage-a-redirect-request-after-a-jquery-ajax-call

Comment: Why you are using AJAX if you need to redirect after success? Easier way is to create a normal controller action for this.

Comment: @Troyer, Yes it can. But in this case, I have to keep using a link with the post method. No get method.  And the solution is to use ajax. If I using form submit, it change my css view

Answer (score 1):

You can redirect to route in Ajax success which will call your desired funtion in controller like this:

**Ajax**

```
success:function(){
    window.location.href(base_url+"/get/data");
});
```

For this to work, you should have following route and controller function

**Route**

```
Route::get('/get/data','YourController@getData');
```

**Controller**

```
public function getData(){      

    $list = // here write code to get desired data.

    return view('shop.index',compact('list'));
}
```

Hope you understand.